# Is it possible to use windows drivers in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, kernel

My KWorld UB430-AF dongle stopped working over 1 year ago. An Ubuntu user detected and then reported a kernel issue as the source of the problem (regression of kernel drivers): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1266328, which wasn't fixed as of today. Can anyone please give me a clue of how to use the device's Windows drivers on Ubuntu? Or should I forget about it and just throw the device away? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ndiswrapper is an 'app' for installing wifi drivers, but for your dongle i don't think there is something similar.

You could try installing another kernel from Ubuntu's kernel archive if you find relevant info that it works with your device, but i can't recommend doing it..